# Counting the number of 1's that appear in a pandas string

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
my_dict = {'my_var': {0: u'000000',
  1: u'100000',
  2: u'000000',
  3: u'000000',
  4: u'000000',
  5: u'010000',
  6: u'000100',
  7: u'110100',
  8: u'110101',
  9: u'000000',
  10: u'010000',
  11: u'000100',
  12: u'000100',
  13: u'000100',
  14: u'011101',
  15: u'000000',
  16: u'111110',
  17: u'001010',
  18: u'011111',
  19: u'111111'},
 'id': {0: u'115',
  1: u'143',
  2: u'155',
  3: u'129',
  4: u'003',
  5: u'100',
  6: u'102',
  7: u'004',
  8: u'889',
  9: u'349',
  10: u'772',
  11: u'759',
  12: u'346',
  13: u'340',
  14: u'541',
  15: u'924',
  16: u'234',
  17: u'661',
  18: u'965',
  19: u'779'}}
```

I'd like to count the occurrence of ones for each case, such that the final output is number of 1's per id. In the final output, id 115 has zero 1's while id 143 has one.

I had an idea of splitting the string into six columns, and then summing that up, but that sounded very inefficient, besides that I failed to implement it.

Help is always appreciated.

Comment: Show what you tried

Comment: Why do you have two lists instead of a dictionary that maps id to value?

Comment: You don't need to split anything. `count("1", "011101")` returns 4

Comment: I'm curious, what's the context for this?

Comment: Sure -- this data is for six products all stored as a string per id. For example assume we have 6 types of automobiles, Auto A takes the first position in the string, Auto B, second position etc. So if an id has '100000' it means that individual owns Auto A only, while if someone has '000101' they have the fourth type of automobile and the sixth type. In this case I was interested in counting the number of automobiles each individual has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DataFrame.assign`, `Series.str.count` and `groupby.sum`:

```
df.assign(ones=df['my_var'].str.count('1')).groupby('id', sort=False).sum().reset_index()

     id  ones
0   115     0
1   143     1
2   155     0
3   129     0
4   003     0
5   100     1
6   102     1
7   004     3
8   889     4
9   349     0
10  772     1
11  759     1
12  346     1
13  340     1
14  541     4
15  924     0
16  234     5
17  661     2
18  965     5
19  779     6
```

I assumed that `my_var` column is `string` type, if not, replace:

```
df['my_var'].str.count('1')
```

With

```
df['my_var'].astype(str).str.count('1')
```

Comment: Believe it or not this is 2x as fast `pd.Series([s.count('1') for s in df['my_var']], index=df.index).groupby(df['id']).sum()`   Pandas .str accessor is slow and loopy.  Often you are better using list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you guys. Learning python, slowly.

Comment: Interesting, did not know that @ScottBoston. Always assumed that the `str` accessors were up there in terms of speed.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand `id` is unique in each row. If that's true, you can use simple `str.count`:

```
df['num_1'] = df['my_var'].transform(lambda x: x.count('1'))

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    my_var   id  num_1
0   000000  115      0
1   100000  143      1
2   000000  155      0
3   000000  129      0
4   000000  003      0
5   010000  100      1
6   000100  102      1
7   110100  004      3
8   110101  889      4
9   000000  349      0
10  010000  772      1
11  000100  759      1
12  000100  346      1
13  000100  340      1
14  011101  541      4
15  000000  924      0
16  111110  234      5
17  001010  661      2
18  011111  965      5
19  111111  779      6
```